# How to show multiple Location on google map using php and mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

I have the following code, it works fine but picks only one location,
I have multiple location against 'cid' and I want to get and display all the location.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <?php
    $sql = "select * from locator_areas where cid=$city";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
           while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
              ?>
             <script> var myLatLng = {lat: <?php echo $row['latitude'] ?>, lng: <?php echo $row['longitude']?>};</script>

<?php } ?>
    <script>
     function initMap() {
        icon='img/bk-loc.png';
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatLng
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          icon:icon,
          title: "<?php echo $long.' || '. $lat?> "
        });
      }

    </script>
    <script async defer
     src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>

  <script> initMap();</script>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple markers by adding new google.Maps.Marker() multiple times. It would make sense to iterate over a array to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving N positions in one variable. In that variable only the last position is saved. If you want to save N positions in memory you have to use an array. 
To ship PHP variables to Javascript I recomend to use PHP and the PHP function `json_encode`.

In the end of your example, you are calling `initMap`. It is not needed since this function is called from your googleapis script include.

Rewritten code should look like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <?php
    $sql = "select * from locator_areas where cid=$city";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);


    $positions = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        /* <script> var myLatLng = {lat: <?php echo $row['latitude'] ?>, lng: <?php echo $row['longitude']?>};</script>*/

        $positions[] = array(
            'lat' =>   $row['latitude'],
            'lng' =>   $row['longitude'],
            'title' => $row['longitude']. ' || ' .$row['latitude']
        );

    }

    ?>
    <script>

        var positions = <?php echo json_encode($positions) ?>;

    </script>

    <script>
        function initMap() {
            icon='img/bk-loc.png';
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 4,
                center: myLatLng
            });

            positions.forEach(function(position){
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {
                        'lat' : position.lat,
                        'lng' : position.lng
                    },
                    map: map,
                    icon:icon,
                    title: position.title
                });
            });

        }

    </script>
    <script async defer src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should look like this

```
    <?php
    require("phpsqlsearch_dbinfo.php");
    // Get parameters from URL
    $center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
    $center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
    $radius = $_GET["radius"];

    // Start XML file, create parent node
    $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
    $node = $dom->createElement("markers");
    $parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

    / Opens a connection to a mySQL server
    $connection=mysql_connect (localhost, $username, $password);
    if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}

// Search the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

    ?>
```

Check out these links https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

Comment: Hello Sir, I tried this, but did not work. this shows nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple markers by adding  multiple times using for loop. It would make sense to iterate over a array to do this.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <?php
    $sql = "select * from locator_areas where cid=$city";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
           while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
               $i=0;
              ?>


         <script>   var myLatLng = new Array();
        myLatLng[<?php echo $i; ?>] = "<?php echo $value['latitude']; ?> , <?php echo $value['longitude']; ?>"; </script>

<?php 
 $i++;
} ?>
    <script>

var locations = new Array();
            var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0; i < pins.length; i++) {
              var coordinates = pins[i].split(", ");
              locations[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]);
              latlngbounds.extend(locations[i]);
            }

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 9,
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                center: myLatlng,
                draggable: false,
                scrollwheel: false,
                disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

            //var contentString = "<p>I am HTML</p>";

            var image = 'img/bk-loc.png';               
            var markers = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
                markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: locations[i],
                    map: map,
                    title: pin_quick_data[i],
                    icon: image
                });
            }
    </script>
    <script async defer
     src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>

  <script> initMap();</script>

  </body>
```